# Installing openpyxl in python 2.7

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pip, pycharm, openpyxl

I am currently using Python 2.7 and i want to work on Excel sheets. So i found a package called **openpyxl 2.4.0**. I tried installing it by using **pycharm and pip command**. But it shows following error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyxl (from version s: ) 
No matching distribution found for openpyxl
```

should i go for another version of python? Please help me with issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please share the commands that you tried for installing openpyxl

Comment: @Eknath The command i tried is "pip install openpyxl". Also i tried installing using Pycharm. Both didnt work.

Comment: can u try once "pip install openpyxl==2.4.0"

Comment: @Eknath same error

Comment: Thank you @Eknath you save my life!

Answer (score 0):

System install of openpyxl may not work in lower Python versions. You can try to install development edition of openpyxl.
You can follow the below link to install development edition of Python. This way you won't impact package installs in your machine.
[https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/windows-development.html#:~:text=Install%20a%20development%20version%20of,pip%20install%20%2De%20.&text=Releases%20for%20legacy%20versions%20of%20Python%3A&text=0%20for%20Python%202.7](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/windows-development.html#:%7E:text=Install%20a%20development%20version%20of,pip%20install%20%2De%20.&text=Releases%20for%20legacy%20versions%20of%20Python%3A&text=0%20for%20Python%202.7)

Answer (score -4):

Write in pycharm terminal:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Comment: Please explain this with a little more detail and mark up the code :)